# I want to select one row of datagrid and change background color, but my selection is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My code is this:

```
if (PointVal <= Convert.ToDouble(Mrtlbl.Text))
{
    var Srow = PointsDbGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(PointsDbGrid.SelectedItem) as DataGridRow;

    if (Srow == null)
    {
        PointsDbGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
        Srow = PointsDbGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(PointsDbGrid.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow;
    }

    Srow.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;
    // Srow.Tag = "ChangedBackground";
    // rw.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;
}
```

Why is `Srow` always is null?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTAdo.png)

Comment: Your container can't be a DataGridRow

Comment: Why you want to do this in code behind ? Can't you just do background color change in XAML ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have actually selected an item? What does PointsDbGrid.SelectedItem return?

Comment: Yes i'm sure,if you check image below my question,you understand